# Ordering issue with orderby in Super Search

Tags: ee2, solspace, search, supersearch

How do you force the "orderby=" parameter to use a custom field like "alphabet" as the lead in Super Search.

Using it +asc doesn't work, nor does using it alone. It still prioritizes the results by entry date.

We've tried a few variations to make sure we were using it line with the documentation, but `orderby="title+workers-name+asc"` whereas workers-name was the custom field

Thanks in advance.

Code Sample:

```
{exp:super_search:search channel="workplace" orderby="title+workers_lname+asc"}
<form action="{path='workplace/search-results'}" method="post" id="search_form">
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{csrf_token}" />
```

Comment: Are you setting this via a parameter on the `results` tag, or via your form's `POST`? Anything set in `POST` will override tag parameters.

Comment: OK, so now check your form and make sure you're not also setting an `orderby` parameter there, as it will win.

Comment: So I posted a small code sample if that helps.

Comment: Is your field `workers-name`? `workers_lname`? Make sure you have the name right. Let's say it's `workers_lname`, try `orderby="title+asc+workers_lname+asc"`. You're missing an `+asc` or `+desc` next to `title`. Also, what is the fieldtype for `workers_lname`? That can be important because Super Search will look at the `exp_channel_data` table for ordering.

Comment: Also, why is the `orderby=""` parameter with `{exp:super_search:search}`? That isn't a valid parameter (docs: https://solspace.com/docs/super_search_2/search/#parameters). If you want orderby in the **search form**, use a form field for "orderby" (users can edit this since it's a form field). If you _don't_ want users to be able to access the "orderby" field, use the `orderby=""` parameter on your **results template**, i.e. where `{exp:super_search:results}` (_:results_, not _:search_) is used.

Comment: Thank you -- ultimately the answer was to utilize the results page to achieve this instead of search page.